# Is my current transformer rated for 11kV Tranmission line?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, transmission-line, power-engineering, current-transformer

I'm using a current transformer to measure current on HV transmission lines.
Except i'm finding it difficult to find a split core CT that will be rated for 11kV.

My CT that i'm looking at is the DP-58 1000-5A 5VA transformer
It has a maximum voltage 0.72/3kV.

[CT Link](http://www.rpvelectro.com/ourpartners/rpv/DP%20series-Split%20core%20current%20transformers_new.pdf)

How do I know if will be safe on an 11kV line and does anyone else have any other recommendations?

Comment: Where did you get permission to access 11kV? This is not a playground, you should be special trained for the HV, then might you wouldn't ask if 3kV CT is rated for 11kV.

Comment: When you say 'transmission line', do you mean an overhead line with bare conductors, or do you mean an insulated cable? Two very different beasts. I also agree with Marko and Andy: **If you do not know what you are doing, you need to stay away from 11kV.** HV installations should only be designed, or worked on, by electricians and engineers who are trained, deemed competent, and authorised.

Comment: If you have to come here to ask such things, no one should let come nearer than 11km to 11kV.

Comment: You know the line about "the meek shall inherit the earth" that's what's left after the untrained brave, bold and stupid have been playing with the power lines ....

Answer (score 3):

> How do I know if will be safe on an 11kV line

It won't be safe so don't even think about it. If the technical spec states a limit of 3kV then that's its limit.

My recommendation - keep searching for what you want and do not exceed that voltage rating on the data sheet. Any CT you choose should be from a supplier you can believe in or has demonstrably adequate quality standards.

11kV is very dangerous stuff.